# Logger class, How to access it from any method

Tags: php, static-methods

I have a logger class I made and I'm not sure which is the best way to implement it.

The `write()` method in this class needs to be able to be called from any method from within every class in the application.

Previously I was doing Logger::write() havin the method as a static method. It's quick and easy but I have a feeling it's not the best way to do it.

Should I inject an instance of the logger class into my other objects (via constructor or setter method) and then when I need to write to a log call it like:

```
$this->logger->write()
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the method be static?

Comment: If the functioning of your classes depends on it, you should inject it. That way it's clear from the start what dependencies there are and you don't get any surprises when running your application when something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want it to be available within every object? Injecting it everywhere seems very tedious and is not very practical. What if you need to log something inside a static method, a regular function or in the global scope?

Or to put it simply: What is wrong with just calling `Logger::write()`? Maybe you are over-thinking it?

Comment: I want to call it statically but after reading a few articles and watching a few videos about static methods and they are bad according to some people for loads of different reasons and then I read another article and watch another video that says basically the complete opposite it drives me crazy.

Comment: Well personally I often hate the complexity of dependency injections for ie. database and config objects. I either use those statically or I use a base class that holds the initialized objects that i'll use anyway (think App::$Db, App::$Config, App::$Log) But if your methods don't need a full class to function, just make them static. Or allow them to be used both statically and initialized.

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with static methods. I am sure you can find situations where using a static method may not be the best idea, but in this case it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your `public static function write()` has no need to access any properties or methods within your logger class, there is absolutely no reason to not make it static. (As in accessible with Logger::write(). Forcing the object to be initialized is redundant if there is no proper reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you wish to use the class.

If you don't require an instance to use the method then define the method as static and call it statically as `Logger::write()` and that's fine.

But if you require an instance then you will need to decide on how to use that instance throughout your code. For example, you can use [Dependency Injection](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-huh/) to pass the instance around to your code where it's needed. That's the way I would recommend you do it.